# Regex matching a link excluding a word from a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a simple regex detection system of a multiline string containing both text and URLs, let's suppose the string is:

```
this is a list of youtube videos
https://www.youtube.com/watch...
https://www.youfake.com/watch...
https://www.youlube.co.uk/watch...
```

I want regex to get exactly the beginning of the website and also the /watch part, but without matching youtube in any case, in the above string, it should pick **you** from **you**fake but only if **/watch** is present, same as youlube (with the domain) and the /watch part, so it should match line 3 and line 4, without line 2 which is youtube.

The regex I currently have is `(you).*(\.com|\.co.uk).*(\/watch)` however it matches all three links, how can I exclude the exact word 'youtube' while also using 'you' as part of the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(you)(?!tube\b).*(\.co(?:m|\.uk)).*(/watch)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rBAZr4/1).

You can see I added a negative lookahead after `(you)` to make sure there is no match if `you` found is a part of the `youtube` word.

*Details*:

- `(you)` - Group 1: `you`
- `(?!tube\b)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location that is not immediately followed with `tube` and a word boundary
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(\.co(?:m|\.uk))` - Group 2: `.co` and then either `m` or `.uk`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(/watch)` - Group 3: `/watch`.